# If $|G| = n < 60$, and $n$ is composite, then $G$ is not a simple group. Why?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, simple-groups

If $|G| = n < 60$, and $n$ is composite, then $G$ is not a simple group. I am not totally sure how to solve this.

So far, I have tried thinking of every possible theorem I can think of.

A simple group is one where the only normal subgroups are trivial. If $G$ is group of prime order, then it must be a simple group since its only factors are $1$ and the prime order.

In this case, factors of $60 = 2^{2} \times 3 \times5 $. Now, according to Sylow's first theorem, it must contain $p$-groups of order of $4, 3$ and $5$.

And according to Lagrange's theorem, its subgroups must have order $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15$.

I am not really sure how to proceed from here to show that indeed, the group cannot be a simple group. Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: $A_5$ has order $60$ and is simple.

Comment: $n<60$ you mean

Comment: I believe this question does not have a general or simple answer for all groups of composite order $<60$. We will need some case distinction to handle it (maybe not for every composite order but some classes of orders I can say).

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Yes,sorry about that

Comment: The answer may not be "simple", but it is very popular here at this site. There are many posts and detailed references. Another duplicate is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1518912/why-is-it-that-for-n60-the-simple-groups-are-precisely-the-cyclic-groups-m), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3237744/prove-that-there-is-no-nonabelian-simple-group-of-order-less-than-60), and there are more.